# error: 'memcpy_s' was not declared in this scope in gSOAP

Tags: c++, web-services, wcf, gsoap

I need to implement a client proxy for wcf web service using [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) in c++. I used [Getting Started](http://www.genivia.com/dev.html) page (in section "Example gSOAP client (C++)") for generating client proxy to test my web service. When I want to build project using

```
c++ -o calcclient calcclient.cpp soapC.cpp soapcalcProxy.cpp stdsoap2.cpp
```

command I get following errors:

[image]

It seems there are some standard library that does not included in `stdsoap2.cpp`. I use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) as compiler and my OS is Windows 8.

Comment: You included `cstring`? Which MinGW version you're using?

Comment: no. I use MinGw included in code block in http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe

Comment: @Youka I added cstring in stdsoap2.cpp but not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy_s` is a safe version of `memcpy` and normally included with standard libraries. [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wes2t00f.aspx) does it, [MinGW64](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/string.h#L181) too.

With Code::Blocks you get [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) which is behind [MinGW64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and seems not to have the secure API. Just load MinGW64, configure Code::Blocks to use this compiler and all should be fine.

Comment: thanks but there is not MinGW64 in compiler list. The selected compiler is GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: Open **Code::Blocks -> Settings -> Compiler...**, choose or copy _GNU GCC Compiler_ and configure. Tab **Toolchain executables** should refer to MinGW64 with additional path to subcompiler directory, f.e. "E:\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32". Rest is a CB question, easy to solve by web search.

Comment: I got one error and a lot of errors gone! Now my error is: error: 'wctomb_s' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: MinGW seems not to have this version, but `_wctomb_s_l`. Your library seems to have been written for MSVC compilers :/